# async function and updating global variable

Tags: javascript

im trying to load multiple images using an async function and a regular for function, and for some reason only the last image of the called is being loaded onto the dom..
I think it has to do with the global variable however I cant quite get a grip on why.

```js
let imgEl;
const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.images');
function createImage(imgPath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    imgEl = document.createElement('img');
    imgEl.src = imgPath;
    imgEl.addEventListener('load', () => {
      document.querySelector('.images').append(imgEl);
      resolve(imgEl);
    });
    imgEl.addEventListener('error', e => reject(e));
  });
}

async function loadAll(...imgPaths) {
  try {
    const res = await Promise.all(
      imgPaths.map(async imgPath => await createImage(imgPath))
    );
    res.forEach(el => el.classList.add('paralell'));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

loadAll('/img/img-1.jpg', '/img/img-2.jpg', '/img/img-3.jpg');
```

Comment: Yeah, because you only keep one global `imgEl`. Put `let imgEl` *into* your `Promise`…!

Comment: The `load` callback will be executed asynchronously, so it will be executed three times but each time `imgEl` value will be the equal to the last value it has been assigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time the `load` event on any of the images has fired, the value of `imgEl` been overwritten by the last call to `imgEl = document.createElement('img');`.

This means the last image gets appended multiple times (initially adding it to the DOM and then moving it from where it is to … well … the same place several times).

The earlier images get garbage collected as there are no references left to them.

---

Define `imgEl` inside the function you pass to `new Promise`; don't make it a global. It doesn't need to be shared between multiple functions or multiple invocations of the same function.